# How to render image from adjacent multisite blog in twig template (Timber\Image object)

Tags: wordpress, multisite, timber

To no avail, I've been scouring the Timber docs to determine how to render images from an adjacent multisite blog in the main blog's twig templates.

The posts array that gets passed to the twig template is constructed through a loop that calls an extension of `Timber\Post`, during which some posts are processed with `switch_to_blog(2)` + `restore_current_blog()`. The posts in the posts array that are retrieved from blog ID 2 contain all of the correct and expected data, including the `Timber\Image` object.

`array (size=9)
     ...
     5 =>
       array (size=15)
         'ID' => int 7528
         ...
         'image' => 
           object(Timber\Image)[4256]
             ...
             public 'ID' => string '8541' (length=4)`

However, when the twig template renders the post data, it's using the image's ID (8541) against the main blog rather than the blog associated with the image (i.e. blog ID 2). The result, of course, is the displayed image gets called from the main blog using the image ID from the other blog.

I expect that when looping through the posts array, `Timber\Image` needs to be switching to the other blog ID, but not I'm not sure how this is accomplished.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just in the process of doing something like this - my situation is easier beacuse I want to redirect all the images to one blog (one media library for whole WP Multisite).

So I can't provide you with full answear yet but maybe I can point you to the right track track and share problems I've stumbled upon.

First of all I've extended `Timber\Image`, `Timber\Post` and `Timber\ImageHelper`.

In my Post Class I just changed the image class (to mine).

In Image Class you have to add `switch` and `restore` every time WP is using functions like `wp_get_attachment...` etc - so every time when image ID is being converded to url/path.

In ImageHelper you have to work with `_Operate` method - also add `switch` and `restore`.

Problems I still have:

- ACF - I have add a filter to switch to correct blog
- as you see - lots of overriding - updating will be problematic

Also take a look at those two plugins:

- https://github.com/bueltge/multisite-global-media
- https://github.com/johnbillion/network-media-library

they have a bit different approach so maybe it will inspire you in some way.